# Regular expression for no white space at start or end, but allow white space in middle, but also allow only one char inputs:

Tags: .net, regex

Regular expression for no white space at start or end, but allow white space in middle, but also allow only one char inputs:

The closest I have got is : `^([^\s])([\sa-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)([^\s])$`

The problem with this is that it will only pass if the input is three or more chars, I need it to accept a single char and pass. EG:

The following should pass (using " for easy of reading, not required in string)

```
"A"
"A B"
"Hello There"
```

The following should fail

```
" A"
"A "
" A "
" test"
```

also needs to only allow A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ though out, with addition of spaces in middle section but not at start or end

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.` (from the `[regex]` tag description)

Comment: Sorry, also needs to only allow A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ though out, with addition of spaces in middle section but not at start or end

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Non-spaces, optionally followed by multiple groups of spaces then non-spaces:

```
^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$
```

**Edit:**

To include the character restrictions, just replace non-space classes with allowable characters:

```
^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s+[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Also, consider being Unicode friendly and using something like

```
^[-_\p{Alnum}]+(\s+[-_\p{Alnum}]+)*$
```

(assuming your regex interpreter allows it).

Comment: Sorry i missed out that it also needs to only allow  A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ though out, with addition of spaces in middle section but not at start or end

Comment: Could you please explain what this is actually saying? 

^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s+[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$

Comment: It's some non-zero number of allowable non-space characters, optionally followed by multiple suffixes, where each suffix is spaces followed by a non-zero number of allowable non-space characters.

Answer (score 2):

Make everything after the first non-space character optional:

```
^(?=\S)[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]*\S$
```

Comment: This allows you to enter any character as the first character, where it should restrict to a-zA-Z0-9

Comment: Well you didn't say that, did you? Edited.

Comment: sorry, I missed that in the init post. Edited at last minute