# Regular expression for no space at start or end, but allow space in middle but also allow only one char inputs

Tags: javascript, php

My `RegExp` is

```
/^[A-Za-z ]*$/
```

Then what should i write to not allow space at start or end, but allow space in middle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715133/regular-expression-for-no-white-space-at-start-or-end-but-allow-white-space-in

Answer (score 8):

This regular expression will match any strings that conform to your original expression that do not have a space at the beginning or end

```
^(?! )[A-Za-z ]*(?<! )$
```

Comment: @AD7six, less then 2 characters to be precise.

Comment: Have edited so it works for single character strings

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni the original regex didn't specify a need to match numbers

Comment: @NambiNarayanan you have a `;` in the second line

Comment: Nice idea use the negative regex, but using the character group for a single one is unneeded, just use: `^(?! )[A-Za-z ]*(?<! )$` @Tom, it is fairly unfair that you edit your answer and answer to my comment stating it does not make sense. Now it does not, but in the original regex you wrote did accepted number in the begin and end. (It was `^[^\s][A-Za-z ]*[^\s]$`)

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni sorry I am new to answering on SO and was not sure of the etiquette for editing answers. Am I to leave the original (incorrect) answer and add a new one? I have edited it as per your suggestion as well, thank you

Comment: Oh, no. Fixing is fine. Just say in the comments what you did. I am also new, I just find weird that you stated "the original regex didn't specify a need to match numbers" when it was just my point and fixed the answer.

Comment: Caution - As of 08 Feb 2022, [Lookbehind in JS regular expressions](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) is still not supported in [Safari](https://www.apple.com/safari/).

Answer (score 3):

Use this pattern to match in a regex

```
(?=(?:^\w))([A-Za-z ]+)(?<=[^ ])$
```

**Demo**

[**http://regex101.com/r/lM1aQ6**](http://regex101.com/r/lM1aQ6)

I suggest You to use [**trim()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) in php to remove the space at the start and end of the string.

```
$hello  = " Hello World ";
trim($hello);
```

From the **PHP Doc**

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

Comment: The OP specified that they were using regular expressions.

Comment: I think you should allow the empty string, otherwise the OP would have used + and not *. It sounds fairly overcomplicated though.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably split the problem: or it contains no spaces at all, or it contains only in the middle.

```
^[A-Za-z]*$|^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z ]*[A-Za-z]$
```

It will accept "aa", "a", "a ab c", but not " " or " a"...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
<?php 
echo trim("  spaces and spaces    "); // outputs: "spaces and spaces"
?>
```

Comment: I know, but maybe he doesn't know about the existence of the trim() function in php.

Comment: @AD7six, Why do you think `trim()` doesn't answer the question ?

Comment: The regex in the question is alpha-only - using trim you can't enforce a character range e.g. "Ñ", or a number, should fail according to the question and using trim is simply not functionally equivalent. Same for the other "use trim" answer.

Comment: @shankar you mean apart from thr obvious? Trim modifies a variable, a regex is just a pattern match in a very limited scenario they overlap (`$noLeadingTrailingSpace = trim ($string) === $string;`).

Comment: @AD7six, The OP is going to mark a string valid which does not have spaces at the begining or end.. so in that case , a `trim` exactly does the job. In my honest opinion , a regex is not at all required in this case.

Comment: Ignoring the char range used in the question, trim does not mark a string as valid it _makes_ it "valid", and that's assuming a php , not js, solution is desired in addition to being appropriate.  I stand by my firdt comment (unless the question is edited to clarify).

Comment: You have both made your point. Regex is needed to verify if an input is valid. Trim will make the input valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will for you,

```
\b^([^\s]|[a-zA-Z])\s+[a-zA-Z]\b
```

Here,

- \b denotes word boundary.
- ^\s to disallow white-space.
- | is an alternation

And thanks for sharing.