# regex: Allow white space only if character is input in Polymer

Tags: regex, polymer, whitespace

I'm using Polymer 1.0 with the paper-input's "pattern" parameter.

- I need the field to require any character (not white space)
- White space is optional

`^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s+[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715133/regular-expression-for-no-white-space-at-start-or-end-but-allow-white-space-in) does just that, except disallows white space in the beginning and end, and disallows non-letter and number characters. I would like to allow white space in the beginning and end.

After receiving the answer `\s*[\S]+(\s+[\S]+)*\s*` works perfectly because it allows any characters including special characters.

Comment: suitable name you've got there

Comment: So, you’d be happy with just at least one non-whitespace character anywhere in the content? Then simply ask for that.

Comment: Yes and I just found out this regex does not allow other non-number/letter characters.

Comment: I don't know what Polymer is, but wouldn't just `\S` do that?

Comment: Only \S? No melpomene.

Comment: @VagueExplanation Why not?

Comment: \S allows any non-whitespace character, but not 1) REQUIRE any non-whitespace character 2)White space is optional.

Comment: @VagueExplanation That's wrong.

Comment: \S only allows one character. Try it for yourself for Polymer's pattern property.

Comment: @VagueExplanation Then why did you use `^` and `$` in your original attempt?

Comment: I deleted my last comment because [\S] (in brackets) does not work either. I don't have an answer for your question really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\s*` right after the `^` and also before the `$`

This will allow zero-or-more spaces before the first character and after the last one.

Comment: Thank you! That works. I'm just figuring out the best way to allow special characters too, then I'm golden.