# How to restrict use of Leading and Trailing spaces in the textbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, alert

I have multiple `input` fields with different values. I can edit them but cannot be empty (if empty show an alert). When I am editing if I edit them with blank spaces i used `trim` to not allow that.But,I am able to edit the `input` with more spaces at the start and end with a word in between.I don't need this.

How to achieve the following ?

a)Should not start with space.

b)No spaces after the word,if i have one word.

```
<input type="text" class="selector" value="new">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="old">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="newest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="oldest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="older">
```

```
$('.selector').on('blur',function () {
  var current_value = $.trim($(this).val());
  $(this).attr('value',current_value);
  console.log(current_value);
  if ($('.selector[value="' + current_value + '"]').not($(this)).length > 0 || current_value.length == 0 ) {
    $(this).focus();
    alert('You cannot use this');
  }
});
```

My [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/a910xkoL/)

Comment: Please include the relevant JavaScript in your question also, as Roko has kindly done on your behalf this time.

Comment: Thanks for edit @Roko.@David it is in my fiddle.

Comment: And it should be in your question, not (only) in the Fiddle. Don't make us chase around the internet for the pleasure of helping you. If your code is hosted externally and that site falls over, dies or is reorganised, then the question becomes nonsensical at best, and is of no use to anyone else in future.

Comment: @DavidThomas Sure from next question.Thanks

Comment: @IamRaviteja :  Check the answer my me. Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: @IamRaviteja It can be more simpler like this: http://jsfiddle.net/a910xkoL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this

```
$(this).val(current_value);
```

instead of this

```
$(this).attr('value', current_value);
```

Comment: working fine in my fiddle but not in my real project

Comment: If not working, then explain what problem you are facing @IamRaviteja

Comment: @MyWay Sorry! my mistake, I used uppercase letter instead of lower

Answer (score 0):

*Check if first index of space is 0 or last index is end of string then show alert.*

Add the following Condition:

```
if($(this).val().indexOf(" ") == 0 || $(this).val().lastIndexOf(" ") == ($(this).val().length -1) ){
       alert('You cannot use this');
    }
```

Check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a910xkoL/1/)

or **Snippet**:

```js
$('.selector').on('blur', function() {
  var current_value = $.trim($(this).val());
  $(this).attr('value', current_value);
  console.log(current_value);
  if ($('.selector[value="' + current_value + '"]').not($(this)).length > 0 || current_value.length == 0) {
    $(this).focus();
    alert('You cannot use this');
  } else
  if ($(this).val().indexOf(" ") == 0 || $(this).val().lastIndexOf(" ") == ($(this).val().length - 1)) {
    alert('You cannot use this too');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="selector" value="new">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="old">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="newest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="oldest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="older">
```

Answer (score 0):

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a910xkoL/2/)

```
$('.selector').on('blur',function () {
    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
    if($(this).val() == "") {
      alert("Empty values not allowed!");
      this.focus();
    }
});
```

**Explanation**: 
First trim the values, then check if empty. If empty raise the alert and focus the box

Answer (score 0):

I would use input pattern attribute:

```
<input type="text" class="selector" value="new" pattern="^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$" />
```

Regex found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715133/regular-expression-for-no-white-space-at-start-or-end-but-allow-white-space-in#answer-14715203).

Answer (score 0):

To remove spaces at the start and get the value (removes all spaces from left and right edges of the string.):

```
var value = $.trim($("input").val());
```